# How to view queries exucuted few days back in Oracle database version 11g

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I want to view the SQL queries executed a few days back in Oracle database version 11g. Can I get a query for that ?

Comment: What edition of Oracle?  Are you licensed to use the AWR?  Do you have Statspack installed?  Are you looking only for the top SQL statements?  Or are you trying to get every SQL statement regardless of how resource-intensive it was?

Answer (score 0):

If you have appropriate permissions, (such as `SELECT ANY DICTIONARY`) you can query the dynamic view V$SQL and if the statements of interest were invoked a lot, or if there wasn't much activity in the database, the SQL may still be in the shared pool.  Try something like

```
set long 12000   
select sql_id, last_active_time, executions, 
    sql_text  -- or full_sql_text if you want more than just the first 1000 characters of the SQL
from v$sql
where last_active_time between trunc(sysdate)-2  and trunc(sysdate)-1
order by last_active_time;
```

to get all SQL invoked two days ago.  Also, as Justin alluded to, if you are using AWR (Advanced Workload Repository), the default setup of that has details on the last 7 days of activity in the database, including high resource usage SQL; and using the Oracle report script `@?/rdbms/admin/awrrpt` you can specify the date/time range to view high activity SQL and a boatload of of other statistics.

Answer (score -1):

Not possible unless you have saved it before closing your developer

Comment: That's not true. See [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25513/statviews_4052.htm#REFRN23447) and [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25513/statviews_4053.htm#REFRN23448)